# Error installing Kali from a USB flash drive

Tags: linux, usb

I’m trying to install Kali from a USB flash drive (created by Universal USB Installer) on my Samsung NC10 that has no CD reader. When the graphical installer need the files from the CD it can’t find them. I tried unplug the USB flash drive and replug but it does not work. Also I try using some commands but they failed. What can I do to setup?

Answer (score 0):

[Kali Linux Official Documentation](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) recommends using the Win32 Disk Imager application to create a bootable Kali Linux USB on Windows.

> 1. Plug your USB drive into an available USB port on your Windows PC, note which drive designator (e.g. `F:\`) it uses once it mounts, and
>      launch the Win32 Disk Imager software you downloaded.
> 2. Choose the Kali Linux ISO file to be imaged and verify that the USB drive to be overwritten is the correct one. Click the *Write* button.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Once the imaging is complete, safely eject the USB drive from the Windows machine.
> 4. Check in your computer's BIOS/UEFI settings that USB device, not CD is the first boot device. You can now use the USB device to boot into Kali Linux.

Win32 Disk Imager has a *MD5 Hash* checkbox to verify the checksum of the Kali Linux ISO file that you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me.
I remake the image from Kali Linux on my pendrive using Rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie/), before I was using Universal USB Installer.
When the message "Failed to Detect and Mount CD-ROM" appears on the install I unplug the device and wait 30 seconds before plug again. After plug I wait more 30 seconds and click in "Continue".
The problem occurs because the file system.